# Show special characters in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with my VS Code. When trying to modify a file that contains special characters like `"á"`, `"ñ"`, `"ó"` etc., the special characters are replaced with a question mark.  (See image below.)

Although, this can be solved easily from the back of Visual Studio Code, changing the language type to "Windows 1252", because at first it worked for me. But now, even if I change it to that language, the signs are still there.

[image: Screen shot of text in VSCode showing wrong display of non-ASCII characters]

Comment: have you tried setting the encoding to `UTF-8`

Comment: That is the one that came by default in VS Code. and it looked the same

Comment: that means you have to find out what the true encoding is, and also let the compiler know the encoding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup Visual Studio Code to detect and set the correct encoding on file open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528384/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-to-detect-and-set-the-correct-encoding-on-file-o)

Comment: No, I already tried all the types of decoding that VS Code offers and nothing. However, luckily I had a somewhat old backup with that fixed, and I used it. To my misfortune, I had to remake a lot of code

Answer (score 0):

the files that you opened before you made the changes to the encoding have been auto-overwritten and the original characters were replaced with the unknown-character character